# Dynamically swapping out or toggling visibility of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a `TreeView` in a form, that is dock-filled to a groupbox. The problem to solve is, that there is an operation that is run on a `Task`, which loads data from a server application. When this is running, there should be a progress indicator displayed in the location of the `TreeView`. That is, it should be shown instead of the `TreeView`, and take its place fully. The following is what the code for this looks like:

```
private async void preload_data(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        // the treeView should be disabled/invisible at this point
        // make the CircularProgressBar enabled/visible

        // get the information from the server
        await Configuration.network.fetch_stuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // something bad happened
    }
    finally
    {
        // whatever happened, the treeView should be back 
    }
}
```

The `CircularProgressBar` (a third-party control) should appear as in the code above, and should replace the `TreeView`. It should fill the exact same space as the `TreeView` would, which is dock-filled. Below is a screenshot of this:
[image]

This form and all its controls have been designed in the designer, and I don't want to do it there, I want to do it programmatically. What is the best way to go about this? I have looked at examples of `Controls.Remove()` and `Controls.Add()`, but it's not clear if that fits this purpose.

Comment: So what's the problem here? First forget about removing then re-adding the TreeView.  Hide the TreeView and show the progress before the `await` line, then reverse that in the `finally` block?

Comment: @JQSOFT yes, I have played with it in the meantime, and it seems to work. However, I have realised that the `CircularProgressBar` should not be dock-filled or resized when the window is resized, as it distorts. How can I center it within the space where the `TreeView` is?

Comment: Like: `progress.Location = new Point((itsParent.Width - progress.Width) / 2, (itsParentHeight - progress.Height) / 2);` Or center the progress in the designer and set its `Anchor` property to `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common to change the visual output while actions are running, like you do. Think of disabling buttons, to discourage operators to press the button again, or show something visually, to inform operators about the progress.

For simplicity, without the try-catch

```
private async Task PreloadDataAsync()
{
    this.ShowFetchingData(true);

    // start fetching data, do not await:
    var taskFetchData = Configuration.network.fetch_stuff();

    // while taskFetchData not completed, await some time
    TimeSpan updateTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.250);
    int progressCounter = 0;
    while (!taskFetchData.IsCompleted)
    {
        this.ShowProgress(progressCounter);
        var taskWait = Task.Delay(updateTime);
        await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] {taskFetchData, taskWait};
        // either taskFetchData.IsCompleted, or Delay time waited
        ++progressCounter;
    }

    this.ShowFetchingData(false);
}

private void ShowFetchindData(bool show)
{
    // disable/enable certain buttons, menu items, show progressbar?
    this.ButtonFetchData.Enabled = !show;
    this.MenuFetchData.Enabled = !show;
    this.ProgressBarFetchData.Visible = show;
}   

private bool IsFetchingData => this.ProgressBarFetchData.Visible;

private void ShowProgress(int progress)
{
    this.ProgressBarFetchData.Position = progress;
}
```

For simplicity, I've left out checks for the position in the progress bar, but you get the gist.

Usage:

```
private async void OnButtonFetchData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await this.PreloadDataAsync();
}
```

### Room for improvement

The problem with this is that there is no timeout at all: if FetchStuff does not complete, you are in an endless wait. The method that microsoft proposes is the use of a CancellationToken. Almost every async method has an overload with a CancellationToken. Consider creating one yourself:

```
// existing method:
private async Task<MyData> fetch_Stuff()
{
    await this.fetch_stuff(CancellationToken.None);
}

// added method with CancellationToken
private async Task<MyData> fetch_Stuff(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Call async function overloads with the token,
    // Regularly check if cancellation requested

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        ... // fetch some more data, without waiting too long
    }
}
```

Instead of IsCancellationRequested, consider to throw an exception: ThrowIfCancellationRequested.

Usage:

```
private async Task PreloadDataAsync()
{
    // preloading should be finished within 30 seconds
    // let the cancellationTokenSource request cancel after 30 seconds
    TimeSpan maxPreloadTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(maxPreloadTime))
    {
         await PreloadDataAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

The overload with CancellationToken:

```
private async Task PreloadDataAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    this.ShowFetchingData(true);

    // execute code similar to above, use overloads that accept token:
    try
    {
        var taskFetchData = Configuration.network.fetch_stuff(token);
        TimeSpan updateTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.250);
        int progressCounter = 0;
        while (!taskFetchData.IsCompleted)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            this.ShowProgress(progressCounter);
            var taskWait = Task.Delay(updateTime, token);
            await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] {taskFetchData, taskWait};
            // either taskFetchData.IsCompleted, or Delay time waited
            ++progressCounter;
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCancelledException exc)
    {
         this.ReportPreloadTimeout();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.ShowFetchingData(false);
    }
}
```

Or if you want a button that cancels the task:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null;

private book IsPreloading => this.CancellationTokenSource != null;

private async Task StartStopPreload()
{
    if (!this.IsPreloading)
       StartPreload();
    else
       CancelPreload();
}

private async Task StartPreload()
{
    // preload not started yet; start it without timeout;
    try
        {
            this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await PreloadDataAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCancelledException exc)
        {
            this.ReportPreloadCancelled();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            this.cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The method where operators can stop preloading:

```
private async void StopPreload()
{
    this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    // the method that created this source will Dispose it and assign null
}
```

All you have to do is create buttons / menu items to start / stop preloading

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `Visible` properties of controls.